# Array with type map

Tags: dictionary, interface, go

So here is the array

```
parts:[map[content:Phillip,

This section pertains to terminated employees who are paid out in the year following the termination event.  The way the tax law works, the tax basis for your share distribution will be based on the closing stock price the day preceding notification to the transfer agent.  As such, we will distribute net shares calculating the proper withholding at fair market value the day prior to notifying the transfer agent.  We will be distributing the shares reflected on your 9/30/01 statement (6,606 shares plus cash for fractional shares).  If you would prefer to settle the taxes with a personal check, we can distribute gross shares.  Please let me know you preference.

As you know, we are in the process of transferring recordkeeping services from NTRC to Hewitt.  As such, we have a CPA, Larry Lewis, working with us to audit and set up transition files.  He has become our department expert on the PSA account (much more knowledgeable than myself)  and the various plan provision amendments.  If you would like, we can set up a conference call with you, myself, and Larry to go over the payment methodology.  Please let me know a date and time that is convenient for you.

Thanks,

Renee

 -----Original Message-----
From:   Allen, Phillip K.
Sent:   Thursday, November 01, 2001 8:26 AM
To: Ratcliff, Renee
Subject:

Renee,

Thank you for digging in to the issue of Deferred Phantom Stock Units.  It is clear that the payment will be made in shares.  However, I still don't understand which date will be used to determine the value and calculate how many shares.  The plan document under VII.  Amount of Benefit Payments reads "The value of the shares, and resulting payment amount will be based on the closing price of Enron Corp. common stock on the January 1 before the date of payment, and such payment shall be made in shares of Enron Corp. common stock."  Can you help me interpret this statement and work through the numbers on my account.

Thank you,

 Phillip Allen

 contentType:text/plain]]
```

The issue I am running into is trying to "content" I have tried things like

```
t := v["parts"][0].(map[string]interface{})
```

and that didn't work as well as a few other things that got me further down a rabbit hole.

the parts is inside of another map string interface.

This is the error that i keep getting

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}
```

Here is the JSON object I am parsing.

```
{
    "X-cc": "", 
    "From": "renee.ratcliff@enron.com", 
    "X-Folder": "\\PALLEN (Non-   Privileged)\\Allen, Phillip K.\\Inbox", 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "7bit", 
    "X-bcc": "", "X-Origin": "Allen-P", 
    "To": ["k..allen@enron.com"], 
    "parts": [{
      "content": "Phillip,\r\n\r\nThis section pertains to terminated employees who are paid out in the year following the termination event.  The way the tax law works, the tax basis for your share distribution will be based on the closing stock price the day preceding notification to the transfer agent.  As such, we will distribute net shares calculating the proper withholding at fair market value the day prior to notifying the transfer agent.  We will be distributing the shares reflected on your 9/30/01 statement (6,606 shares plus cash for fractional shares).  If you would prefer to settle the taxes with a personal check, we can distribute gross shares.  Please let me know you preference.\r\n\r\nAs you know, we are in the process of transferring recordkeeping services from NTRC to Hewitt.  As such, we have a CPA, Larry Lewis, working with us to audit and set up transition files.  He has become our department expert on the PSA account (much more knowledgeable than myself)  and the various plan provision amendments.  If you would like, we can set up a conference call with you, myself, and Larry to go over the payment methodology.  Please let me know a date and time that is convenient for you.\r\n\r\nThanks,\r\n\r\nRenee\r\n\r\n -----Original Message-----\r\nFrom: \tAllen, Phillip K.  \r\nSent:\tThursday, November 01, 2001 8:26 AM\r\nTo:\tRatcliff, Renee\r\nSubject:\t\r\n\r\nRenee,\r\n\r\nThank you for digging in to the issue of Deferred Phantom Stock Units.  It is clear that the payment will be made in shares.  However, I still don't understand which date will be used to determine the value and calculate how many shares.  The plan document under VII.  Amount of Benefit Payments reads \"The value of the shares, and resulting payment amount will be based on the closing price of Enron Corp. common stock on the January 1 before the date of payment, and such payment shall be made in shares of Enron Corp. common stock.\"  Can you help me interpret this statement and work through the numbers on my account.\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\n\r\nPhillip Allen\r\n\r\n", 

    "contentType": "text/plain"}], 
    "X-FileName": "PALLEN (Non-Privileged).pst", 
    "Mime-Version": "1.0", 
    "X-From": "Ratcliff, Renee </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=RRATCLI>", 
    "Date": {"$date": 1004725111000}, 
    "X-To": "Allen, Phillip K. </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Pallen>", 
    "Message-ID": "<19495537.1075862165839.JavaMail.evans@thyme>", 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=us-ascii", "Subject": "RE:"
}
```

Here is the code.

http://play.golang.org/p/rJPTjvoM_t

Comment: These are enron emails from back in 2011 or something like that when the whole scandal was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please post an actual example of what you have tried and what you are trying to do.

arrays of maps and maps of array behave like any other types.

In your example, it looks like you want a `map[string][]map[string]interface{}` but you have `map[string][]interface{}` with the content of your interface being an `[]interface{}`

Here are some example of use of maps/interface/array/slices + a the failure that you shown. (http://play.golang.org/p/gmH_nVPppx)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Content struct {
        name string
}

func main() {
        arrayOfMap := [2]map[string]Content{
                {"part1": {name: "Philip"}},
                {"part2": {name: "John"}},
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", arrayOfMap[0]["part1"].name)

        mapOfArray := map[string][2]Content{
                "parts": {
                        {name: "Philip"},
                        {name: "John"},
                },
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", mapOfArray["parts"][0].name)

        mapOfArrayOfMap := map[string][2]map[string]Content{
                "parts": {
                        {"subpart": Content{name: "Philips"}},
                },
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", mapOfArrayOfMap["parts"][0]["subpart"].name)

        mapOfArrayOfInterface := map[string][2]interface{}{
                "parts": {
                        map[string]interface{}{"content": Content{name: "Philips"}},
                },
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", mapOfArrayOfInterface["parts"][0].(map[string]interface{})["content"].(Content).name)

        mapOfArrayOfSliceInterface := map[string][2][]interface{}{
                "parts": {
                        {
                                map[string]interface{}{
                                        "content": Content{name: "Philips"},
                                },
                        },
                },
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", mapOfArrayOfSliceInterface["parts"][0][0].(map[string]interface{})["content"].(Content).name)

        v := map[string][]interface{}{
                "parts": []interface{}{
                        0: []interface{}{nil},
                },
        }
        // This will fail as shown in the given example.
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", v["parts"][0].(map[string]interface{}))
}
```

Comment: Hopeully this helps I went ahead and just posted it in a play.golang

http://play.golang.org/p/rJPTjvoM_t


example of the JSON is attached above

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting a bit without changing the logic. You are tryging to access map[string]interface{} as a slice. You should do a type assertion to map[string][]interface{} to do this. http://play.golang.org/p/I2rJe22J_l

Comment: But usually, you do not want to unmarshal to an interface. It is better to know your data and to unmarshal to a known type. http://play.golang.org/p/F3Y1TG5-XY.

Comment: The file has hundreds of single json objects not in an array on their own line, which is why I split the full file read on \n which created the array

Comment: I also tried using the declared types above on my code... Content and Inner and it returns {[]}

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after taking numerous things from the comments above... I want to say what @creack had was the closest thing to being able to get the value of "content" from the multi dimensional interface type is the link below.

http://play.golang.org/p/urBQ8NxSo8